# Arranging books on the shelf.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

There are five distinct computer science books, three distinct mathematics
books, and two distinct art books. In how many ways can these
books be arranged on a shelf if no two of the three mathematics books
are together?

I am getting $3507840$ by doing `10! - (3*8!)`. Is it correct?

Comment: It seems to me there are considerably fewer ways to do it. It might help if you would explain your reasoning.

Comment: I just want to confirm if this way is correct.

Comment: I think it is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Arrange the non-maths books, $7!$ ways.  There are now $8$ gaps between books (including a "gap" at each end of the row).  Choose one of these gaps for the first maths book, a different gap for the second and a different gap for the third.

Answer: $7!\times8\times7\times6$.

Comment: This is elegant, nice! +1

Comment: what if two of the mathematics books are together and one is separate? how can we solve that?

Comment: @ZulfiqarTariq Choose which two books go together.  Choose which order they are in, then stick them together so they are like one book.  Then proceed as above pretending that you have two books not three.

Answer (score 3):

Let's count the number of ways we can arrange the books so that there *are* at least two math books adjacent.

---

The number of ways we can choose the pair that is adjacent is $3$, and if we include the $2$ ways to order the pair we get $6$ possibilities for the book pair. We can think of the collection of books now as being $9$ books: $7$ non-math books, $1$ math book, and $1$ pair of math books that is inseparable. There are $9!$ ways to arrange these. So we have $$9! \cdot 6$$

But we've overcounted the cases in which all three math books are adjacent. How many such cases are there? Well *that's* the same as there being $8$ books on the shelf: $7$ non-math books and $1$ giant trilogy of math books, for $8!$ possibilities, times the $3!=6$ ways to arrange the math books within the three-book thing. This gives $$8! \cdot 6$$

Since we've counted each of the three-adjacent cases exactly twice, and we want to count them only once, this means there are $$9! \cdot 6 - 8! \cdot 6$$ ways to arrange the books so that there *are* at least two math books adjacent.

---

But we want the number of ways so that they *aren't* adjacent. So we can subtract from the total number of arrangements, which is $10!$, to get our final answer

$$10! - (9! \cdot 6 - 8! \cdot 6) = \boxed{1693440}$$

Comment: is this answer 9!⋅6−8!⋅6 going to include the cases where all three books are together? if yes then how we can find where only two books can be togather? and one always sperate?